How is verbal no encryption?
Say we encrypt E as 1 4 4 where sum of first and last is 5 which is alphabet no and middle is dummy, then what is the increase of intelligence. If children play such games of encryption of sentances with similar crypts, then will we feel more secure? Shall the whole group follow this if we meet again?
All international/indian languages start at say 482 etc.

This makes no sense.
